# With R : How to limit the number of columns in R while using melt

Tags: r, ggplot2

Kindly can you please help me in this problem.

I want to limit the number of columns from my data set while plotting it through ggplot. From the following data set I want to plot only columns LOC, TIME, IFLR, OFLR, CT,ICT,OCT.
My data frame is :

`LOC    TIME            F   AT  IFLR    OFLR    CT      ICT     OCT     DT 
Point A 8/1/2014 0:03   0   47  2588    2553    4185    1765    2638    877
Point A 8/1/2014 0:06   0   47  2588    2553    4185    1765    2638    877
Point A 8/1/2014 0:08   0   47  2571    2540    4214    1765    2643    877
Point A 8/1/2014 0:14   0   47  2601    2555    4204    1765    2606    877
Point A 8/1/2014 0:19   0   47  2585    2555    4201    1767    2635    877
Point A 8/1/2014 0:22   0   45  2585    2555    4201    1767    2635    877
Point A 8/1/2014 0:24   0   45  2597    2547    4190    1765    2635    877
Point A 8/1/2014 0:29   0   45  2553    2532    4189    1756    2636    877
Point A 8/1/2014 0:34   0   45  2558    2555    4195    1763    2641    877
Point A 8/1/2014 0:39   0   45  2580    2554    4193    1748    2609    877
.
.
.
.
Point A 8/2/2014 3:05   0   51  2570    2556    4187    1793    2810    901
Point A 8/2/2014 3:10   0   51  2578    2549    4200    1792    2816    900
Point A 8/2/2014 3:15   0   51  2590    2543    4200    1790    2810    900
Point A 8/2/2014 3:19   0   50  2590    2543    4200    1790    2810    900
Point A 8/2/2014 3:20   0   50  2567    2546    4187    1787    2810    899
Point A 8/2/2014 3:25   0   50  2580    2541    4188    1778    2799    897
Point A 8/2/2014 3:30   0   50  2550    2531    4207    1781    2799    894
Point A 8/2/2014 3:35   0   50  2586    2578    4188    1769    2788    894
Point A 8/2/2014 3:35   1   50  2586    2578    4188    1769    2788    894
Point A 8/2/2014 3:40   0   50  2573    2531    4197    1770    2787    894
Point A 8/2/2014 3:45   0   50  2595    2532    4194    1768    2790    894
.
.
.
Point A 8/3/2014 13:53  0   47  2556    2539    4192    1766    2615    939
Point A 8/3/2014 13:58  0   47  2571    2553    4163    1749    2598    940
Point A 8/3/2014 14:02  0   46  2571    2553    4163    1749    2598    940
Point A 8/3/2014 14:03  0   46  2551    2562    4180    1742    2584    940
Point A 8/3/2014 14:08  0   46  2583    2538    4169    1736    2563    940
Point A 8/3/2014 14:13  0   46  2591    2516    4185    1736    2574    940
Point A 8/3/2014 14:18  0   46  2591    2516    4185    1736    2574    940
Point A 8/3/2014 14:18  0   46  2544    2546    4197    1752    2585    942
Point A 8/3/2014 14:23  0   46  2563    2551    4196    1747    2595    941
Point A 8/3/2014 14:28  0   46  2579    2543    4189    1757    2597    946
Point A 8/3/2014 14:33  0   46  2589    2563    4183    1767    2608    944
Point A 8/3/2014 14:35  0   47  2589    2563    4183    1767    2608    944
Point A 8/3/2014 14:38  0   47  2588    2558    4190    1778    2622    946
Point A 8/3/2014 14:43  0   47  2575    2544    4175    1780    2597    947
Point A 8/3/2014 14:48  0   47  2583    2546    4171    1778    2623    949
.
.
.`

The in-between dots above indicate that there are more records in my data frame. My data frame spans over a month of data which has around 11000+ records.

Following is the code which I am using

`meltedframe <- melt(mydata, id="TIME")
ggplot(meltedframe, aes(x=TIME, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable)) 
+ geom_line()
+ scale_y_discrete()`

The output which I am getting is: [image]

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use the `measure.vars` argument to define which columns you want melted, see the help page for `melt.data.frame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your data, you just want to filter out the columns F,AT,DT and LOC

There are a million ways to do this, here's one:

```
mydata[,!(names(mydata)) %in% c("F","AT","DT", "LOC")]
```

Then continue on with your `melt` and plot:

```
meltedframe <- melt(mydata, id="TIME")
ggplot(meltedframe, aes(x=TIME, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable)) +  
       geom_line()
```

Comment: your solution worked for me. Can you please let me know how can I plot a proper y-axis. In the graph above, my Y-axis is messed up.

Comment: it looks like your y axis is getting coeerced to a factor because of the "loc" column - see the edit, removing LOC.

Answer (score 0):

you can also filter the melted frame by row with:

```
 meltedframe[variable %in% c("LOC", "TIME", "IFLR", "OFLR", "CT","ICT","OCT"),]
```

Comment: Thank you @Biebiep. I tried with your solution also, and it helped me.